# Having error to fetch k6 when using nebula-bench in NebulaGraph Database

Tags: nebula-graph

With Nebula Graph Bench v1.0.0, I got the git and compiled k6 by `scripts/setup.sh`, and the version of k6 I installed was v0.0.7;

After I executed this command (`python3 run.py stress run`),  it reported an error directly, suggesting that it seems to be a version problem; then I got the k6 of v0.0.9 again, ending up with the same error.

Please help me to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to use a mismatched version of the NebulaGraph bench to the NebulaGraph database as it's complaining graph client version is incompatible.

Refer to https://github.com/nebula-contrib/NebulaGraph-Bench#dependency on the compatibility matrix to get the correct version of NebulaGraph Bench :).